# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetchAll()

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

When I try to send the data I want to put in a query from a form, it gives me this message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':Citta'

Here is the portion of the code from where it gives me the error:

```
    $location = $_POST['Citta'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM test.cliente WHERE test.cliente.Citta = :Citta";

    $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindParam(':Citta', $location, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->execute();

    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
```

I take the input from a form in another page, then the data goes to $location.

I've changed it all to this:

```
    $location = $_POST['Citta'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM lgp.cliente WHERE lgp.cliente.Citta = ?";
    $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bind_param("s", $location);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
```

But now, it gives me this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on bool

I've already added the mysqli report.
I've changed `$result = $statement->fetchAll();` into `$result = $statement->get_result()->fetchAll();`

Now the error is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetchAll()

Comment: mysli and PDO are different api's, please check which one you are using as they have different functionality.

Comment: Looks like you are using the mysqli library, but attempting to use PDO syntax. Apart from both having functions called prepare(), the two libraries don't have a lot else in common, syntax-wise.  https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli has some simple examples of using prepared statements in Mysqli. You can also check the PHP/mysqli documentation to find more. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Hints: mysqli doesn't support named parameters, and parameters are bound with the bind_param function (note the spelling, and all parameters are bound in one function call, not separately). Again, documentation/tutorials can show you all this.

Comment: $location = $_POST['Citta'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test.cliente WHERE test.cliente.Citta = $location";
$statement->execute();
  
But why if I cut everything down to this it still tells me that it doesn't find the column "Milano"(which is the input in the form that goes into $location)?

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM test.cliente WHERE test.cliente.Citta = $location"` this is wrong if you're using prepared statements. It should be `$sql = "SELECT * FROM test.cliente WHERE test.cliente.Citta = ?"` and then `$statement = $conn->prepare($sql); $statement->bind_param("s", $location); $statement->execute();`.

Comment: `it doesn't find the column "Milano"`...this is confusing. Maybe you used the wrong terminology here? Your column name is `Citta`. "Milano" is presumably a value in one of your table rows, in that column. Anyway the issue would be, if `Milano` is a string, then `Citta = $location` would fail because there's no quote marks around the city name...it would cause a SQL syntax error. This is one reason why you should use parameters!

Comment: Regarding your new error... add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` in your script before you create your connection. This will ensure that PHP reports the actual SQL error from mysqli rather than just a PHP error resulting from an earlier unreported SQL failure. It looks like your call to prepare() is failing for some reason, but you need to get the specific error message.

Comment: Re your latest error. There was a typo in my answer, sorry. Should be fetch_all() as per the manual - https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php . You are of course welcome to check the manual yourself, if you think I've made a mistake... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have got confused between `mysqli` and `PDO` syntax. There are a few similarities, but mainly the way they are used is different.

Your code re-written properly in `mysqli` would look like this:

```
$location = $_POST['Citta'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test.cliente WHERE test.cliente.Citta = ?";
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
$statement->bind_param("s", $location);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->get_result()->fetch_all();
```

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php and https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli for more examples.